# Why is my css file not linking with HTML files in django?

Tags: html, css, django

Here is all my code. Why is the CSS file not linked with HTML file? I am not sure of the problem as it doesn't show any error and there isn't any effect on my webpage. I have included my `settings.py`,`base.html`, and `base.css`.
Also, my static folder is outside my app.

`base.html` code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html>
  <head>
     <title>First Project</title>
     <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
  </head>
  <body>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Parvinder</h1>
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`base.css` code

```
body{
  background-color: black;
  color: blue;
}

h1{
  color: red;
}
```

`settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static",'Users/shree/First_Project/static/')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'register',
    'crispy_forms'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'first_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR ,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'first_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

Comment: You have shared your `SECRET_KEY` with everyone. I think that it is supposed to be private so you should change it soon.

Comment: Are you sure about the `STATIC_DIR` setting?

Comment: It looks like you misspelled `STATICFILES_DIRS`. It is supposed to be `STATICFILES_DIRS` not `STATICFILES_DIR`.

Comment: Done @Rayyan Still it didnt work

Comment: What setting are so talking about @arulmr...??

Comment: I think @arulmr is talking about this setting: `STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static",'Users/shree/First_Project/static/')`. You should double check the path.

Comment: Checked here it is C:\Users\shree\First_Project

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```